# Append vs Overwrite using PrintWriter and if Statements

Tags: java

I'm trying to prompt the user to append text to the end of the file or overwrite the file; but when they choose the append option it still overwrites. Any idea why?

```
String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter file name: ");

String appendStr;
char appendChar;
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);
FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(fileName, true);

do {
    appendStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to append to the end of this file? (Y/N) " +
                                            "[File will be over written if you choose not to append.]");
    appendChar = appendStr.charAt(0);
} while (appendChar != 'Y' && appendChar != 'N');

if (appendChar == 'N') {
    // Create PritnWriter object and pass file name names.txt
    outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);
}
else if (appendChar == 'Y') {
    outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileWrite);
}

// Prompt for number of names to be input * init count control var
String namesCountString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number of names to be written to file: ");
int namesCountInt = Integer.parseInt(namesCountString);

// Prompt user for names & write to file
do {
    String inputName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a name to write to file: ");
    outputFile.println(inputName);

    // Decrement count control var
    namesCountInt--;
} while (namesCountInt > 0);

// Close file
outputFile.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

By the time you've got to this block:

```
        else if (appendChar == 'Y') {
            outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileWrite);
        }
```

you have already initialized `outputFile` in this statement:

```
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);
```

and the `PrintWriter(String filename)` constructor has truncated the file. So it's too late to append to it now.

What you need to do is *not* initialize `outputFile` with any particular value; just declare it. You are setting it to an appropriate value later on. Also, you should delay the initialization of `fileWrite` until you actually need it.

You can also make your code much more succinct by removing the declarations of `outputFile` and `fileWrite` and replacing all of the following lines:

```
    if (appendChar == 'N') {
    //Create PritnWriter object and pass file name names.txt
    outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    }
    else if (appendChar == 'Y') {
    outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileWrite);
    }
```

with this one line:

```
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, appendChar == 'Y'));
```

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone that might come across this in the future:

I had tried to declare-but-not-init the outputFile var as: 
`PrintWriter outputFile;`

This gave me a "var has not been initialized" error during compilation. To fix this, I needed to declare and init with null:

`PrintWriter outputFile = null;`

This solved the problem as per DodgyCodeException's advice.